# Mapping pixel color to temperature value on thermal image

Tags: scale, temperature

I have some thermal images with a temperature scale associated.
I'm trying to get for each temperature value the corresponding pixel color.

I've isolated the scales and obtained some jpg files like this one :

[Temperature Scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYXmu.jpg)

The final goal is to find any hot spot with a temperature value higher than 80°, so I can focus only on max values of each scale.

This is an example of my whole image.

[Jpg image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdVqB.jpg)

Comment: Does the range change from one image to the next in the temperature scale? What about the colours?

Comment: The colors are the same for each image, that means white for high values and black for low ones, while the range changes. The highest value is 95°. I can discard images with a max values lower than 80° and detect anomalies for the other ones.